# How to fill out the method -(BOOL)writeToFile in @implementation

Tags: objective-c, macos, interface, implementation, writetofile

Firstly, assume I'm a complete beginner, because I am. And while this may seem stupid, I have no idea how to do this.

I've seen time and time again to call on -(BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString*)path atomically:(BOOL)flag; within my interface so that I can then write data into a file.

That's awesome, but I need to define that method within the implementation, and AppleDev and most of the other topics I've seen on this simply assume I know how to write the implementation, so they haven't really been helpful in that regard.

I apologize if this is a duplicate question, I've been looking for a week, and not found anything, soo... yes.

So I have

```
@interface Objectname: NSObject

-(BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString*)path atomically:(BOOL)flag;
...

@implementation Objectname

-(BOOL)writeToFile:(NSString*)path atomically:(BOOL)flag{
//absolutely no idea what to put here???
}
```

I'm literally looking everywhere for how to print the NSMutableArray of strings onto a file, which the book I am using (since I am a student) makes it seem easy, but the examples in the book do not utilize implementation or interfaces, they just write it in the @autoreleasepool.

Should I call the writetofile in another method? Or just in @autoreleasepool?

I think I should do

```
[NameofMutableArray writetofile:thePathICreatedwithFileHandle];
```

am I on the right path at least?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

writeToFile is already existing and provided to you by the OS for some classes (NSData, NSString, NSDictionary, NSArray). If you want to have such method as part of an interface for your custom object then a simple way is to have a serialization for your object that goes to such type and then use the OS method on it (then there are multiple ways : I advise you to read about NSCoding protocol)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to represent your custom class on disk and be able to restore etc, the 2 most cocoa options are with a keyed archiver or Core Data, keyed archiver is simpler, but it is much harder to serialize relationships between objects. it is up to you to decide the right tool for the job... it could even be simpler, like storing you values as KV pairs in a dictionary and saving the dictionary, this has the effect of limiting you to plist serializable types though, string, number, dict, array.